# SharePoint Online: Rest API not working with people filter for list with more than 5000 items

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, people-picker, list-view-threshold

I'm trying to use SharePoint rest API to get items from a SPO list. It has around 15K items. But I'm using filters and expecting less than 30 items in the result. It works fine when normal columns are used for filtering. But when I use people picker column, it throws the below error:

```
    <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Below is the query I used:

```
https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=ID,Employee/EMail,Employee/Title,Employee/JobTitle,Employee/Department&$expand=Employee/Id&$filter=(Employee/email address removed for privacy reasons%27)
```

Could anyone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the affected column may help you, for more information check out Microsoft's support article on managing large lists:

[Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb)

Comment: The column is already indexed.

Comment: Is the person column single value or multi value?

Comment: It's a single value column.

Comment: Strange, documentation suggests that it's a supported column type for indexing. Have you tried only returning/selecting that people column in your query?

Comment: _api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$select=Employee/EMail&$expand=Employee&$filter=(Employee/EMail eq 'user@domain.com') - tried this and it did not work.

Comment: There are some kinds of lookup columns which can be indexed, but they don't help with the 5,000 limit. People columns (whether single or multi) are a lookup and won't help. You'll need to find some other way of filtering and then you can use the people column filter.

Comment: That's a good point. However, it is a supported column type for indexing. I think @RobinRoy should open a support ticket with Microsoft if there is nothing wrong with his query/implementation.

Comment: Hi @CallumCrowley, thank you for the suggestion. I had opened a ticket with Microsoft. They informed me that this is an expected behavior and all column types are not supported for filtering large lists.

Comment: That's bizarre. I would go back to them because their own documentation suggests otherwise "When you filter or sort by a column that doesn't have an index, an error dialog could appear. To correct, see Add an index manually from List Settings in the settings menu, then Indexed Columns." https://support.microsoft.com/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb

Comment: Hi @CallumCrowley, I tried the same in a trial tenant. REST API call with people picker column as filter failed there as well when item count > 5K. The column was indexed. I wonder if any one actually have made this work after indexing.

Comment: What @Rothrock said makes sense logically but at the same time MSFT say the column is supported for indexing and indexing is the recommended approach for managing large lists. I would recommend you go back to Microsoft support and reference their own support article. They can confirm beyond doubt whether this is a mistake in documentation https://support.microsoft.com/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest set-up I’ve got, & I’ve got it filtering on non-indexed columns with the HTTP call because I have a preceding ID filter limiting things to 5000 or less items per call before the other filters & it is within an Apply to each concurrently running for each batch of 5000 across the entire dataset.
But it still takes 1-4 seconds with the kind of query you describe.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Community-App-Samples/Large-SP-List-Delegation-Workaround-App/td-p/2330721